# ADF API POST issue in a Data flow

Tags: azure, api, rest

I am trying to post data to Smartsheet via REST API in Azure Data Factory (through a **Data flow**).

The error I am getting indicates the issue is in the Body of the request. I have tested my Body in Alteryx, so I know the cURL syntax is correct.

I do not see a field for "Body" or "request query" in the Sink tool Settings, so I thought the body would be composed of all of the fields flowing into the Sink. So, I selected only the one field I needed, that I called "Body", with the value:
`{"cells": [ {"columnId": 58**********60, "value": "ADF Test 1"} ] }`

The ADF error message I got:
`(url:https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/597*********316/rows,request body: Some({"Body":"{\"cells\": [ {\"columnId\": 58**********60, \"value\": \"ADF Test 1\"} ] }"}), request method: POST)`

I noticed the "Body" name is also parsed through the request, so I tried without it. I modified my field to be "cells", and modified the value accordingly:
`[ {"columnId": 58**********60, "value": "ADF Test 1"} ]`

The ADF error message I got:
`(url:https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/597*********316/rows,request body: Some({"cells":"[{\"columnId\": 58**********60, \"value\": \"ADF Test 1\"}]"}), request method: POST)`

I am not sure if the `\` I am getting before each quotation mark is the reason here, or if it's just ADF always displaying it like that in the error messages... Also not sure what the "Some()" does (I suspect it just concatenates all of the fields into one Body, but I may be wrong)... How should the Body field be prepared properly in the Sink, considering the syntax I provided is correct?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The backslash in front of each quotation mark was the issue, as I suspected. The solution was in the very bottom of the Sink Settings. I just had to switch the Format from JSON to None.

[image: Sink Settings]